# Use of unresolved identifier 'self' (CoreData)

Tags: swift, xcode

I am using this line below :

```
self.present(activityViewController, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

And I am getting an error of - Use of unresolved identifier 'self'. Any ideas about how to resolve this? To me it looks as it it is subordinate to the class, but clearly doing something wrong. Any help would be appreciated.

```
  import UIKit
import CoreData



class CoreDataViewController: UIViewController {
  
    
    @IBOutlet weak var CoreDataView: UITableView!
    
    let context = (UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate).persistentContainer.viewContext

    var items:[Checkins]?

    var btnnames = [""]
    
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        
//        CoreDataView.dataSource = self
//        CoreDataView.delegate = self

        storeTranscription()
         // Loads the current data
         getTranscriptions()
        
//        fetchCheckins()
        
        let btn1name = btnnames[0]
        let btn2name = btnnames[1]
        let btn3name = btnnames[2]
        let btn4name = btnnames[3]
        let btn5name = btnnames[4]
        let btn6name = btnnames[5]
        
//        print(btnnames)
        print(btn1name, btn2name, btn3name, btn4name, btn5name, btn6name)
    
    }

    @IBAction func export(_ sender: Any) {
         exportDatabase()
    }
    
    @IBOutlet weak var Table_label: UILabel!
    }

    var CheckinDate: Date? = Date()
    var fetchedStatsArray: [NSManagedObject] = []
    let context = (UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate).persistentContainer.viewContext


    func storeTranscription() {
        //retrieve the entity that we just created
        let entity =  NSEntityDescription.entity(forEntityName: "Checkins", in: context)
        let transc = NSManagedObject(entity: entity!, insertInto: context) as! Checkins

        //set the entity values
        transc.who = "Who"
        transc.reason = "Reason for visit"
        transc.date = CheckinDate

        //save the object
        do {
            try context.save()
            print("saved!")
        } catch let error as NSError  {
            print("Could not save \(error), \(error.userInfo)")
        } catch {

        }
    }

    func getTranscriptions () {
        //create a fetch request, telling it about the entity
        let fetchRequest: NSFetchRequest<Checkins> = Checkins.fetchRequest()

        do {
            //go get the results
            let searchResults = try context.fetch(fetchRequest)
            fetchedStatsArray = searchResults as [NSManagedObject]
            //I like to check the size of the returned results!
            print ("num of results = \(searchResults.count)")
            //You need to convert to NSManagedObject to use 'for' loops
            for trans in searchResults as [NSManagedObject] {
                //get the Key Value pairs (although there may be a better way to do that...
                print("\(trans.value(forKey: "who")!)")
                let mdate = trans.value(forKey: "CheckinDate") as! Date
                print(mdate)
            }

        } catch {
            print("Error with request: \(error)")
        }
    }

    func exportDatabase() {
        let exportString = createExportString()
        saveAndExport(exportString: exportString)
    }


    func saveAndExport(exportString: String) {
        let exportFilePath = NSTemporaryDirectory() + "Checkins.csv"
        let exportFileURL = NSURL(fileURLWithPath: exportFilePath)
        FileManager.default.createFile(atPath: exportFilePath, contents: NSData() as Data, attributes: nil)
        //var fileHandleError: NSError? = nil
        var fileHandle: FileHandle? = nil
        do {
            fileHandle = try FileHandle(forWritingTo: exportFileURL as URL)
        } catch {
            print("Error with fileHandle")
        }

        if fileHandle != nil {
            fileHandle!.seekToEndOfFile()
            let csvData = exportString.data(using: String.Encoding.utf8, allowLossyConversion: false)
            fileHandle!.write(csvData!)

            fileHandle!.closeFile()

            let firstActivityItem = NSURL(fileURLWithPath: exportFilePath)
            let activityViewController : UIActivityViewController = UIActivityViewController(
                activityItems: [firstActivityItem], applicationActivities: nil)

            activityViewController.excludedActivityTypes = [
                UIActivity.ActivityType.assignToContact,
                UIActivity.ActivityType.saveToCameraRoll,
                UIActivity.ActivityType.postToFlickr,
                UIActivity.ActivityType.postToVimeo,
                UIActivity.ActivityType.postToTencentWeibo
            ]

            self.present(activityViewController, animated: true, completion: nil)
            
        }
    }

    func createExportString() -> String {
        var checkinwho: String?
        var checkinreason: String?

        var export: String = NSLocalizedString("who, reason, date \n", comment: "")
        for (index, itemList) in fetchedStatsArray.enumerated() {
            if index <= fetchedStatsArray.count - 1 {
                checkinwho = Checkins.value(forKey: "who") as! String?
                checkinreason = itemList.value(forKey: "reason") as! String?


                let Datevar = Checkins.value(forKey: "date") as! Date
                let whostring = checkinwho
                let reasonstring = checkinreason
                let DateSting = "\(Datevar)"
                export += "\(whostring!),\(reasonstring!),\(DateSting) \n"
            }
        }
        print("This is what the app will export: \(export)")
        return export
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove the } on this line

```
@IBOutlet weak var Table_label: UILabel!
    }
```

and put another } at the end of this file.

Comment: Thank you. I figured it was something simple and silly.